# Spring: How to make class a bean if one constructor-arg is a ref bean but another is not?

Tags: java, spring

I have a class

```
public class MakeMeBean {
  @Autowired private IAmBean var1;
  private IAmNOTBean var2;

  public MakeMeBean() {}

  public MakeMeBean(IAmNOTBean var) {
    this.var2 = var;
  }
}
```

I want to make this class as a bean so I make a `wireup.xml` as

```
<bean id="make-me-bean" class="com.blah.blah.MakeMeBean">
  <constructor-arg index="0" ref=<PUT REFERENCE BEAN HERE>
  <constructor-arg index="1" <I don't want to put anything>
</bean>
```

**Question**
a.) How can I make a bean in which one instance variable is a bean and another not? I don't want to inject var2(another bean in `wireup.xml`)

b.) `<PUT REFERENCE BEAN HERE>` is a bean imported from jar file, how can I make reference to this bean in `wireup.xml`

Comment: Your constructor has only one arg. I'm not clear why you are providing two constructor-args. That can't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just have some beans in context that you created and another half that spring created (at least not that simple), if you want to manage the instances over spring, spring should have the objects on its context. Of course you have the possibility to instantiate the objects in the context, and after the instantiation you could invoke some setters to set some properties.

In order to use another to user another bean, that I suppose comes from another Spring context, the other spring context needs to be imported in the first one. In order to import a context file you can use:

```
<import resource="resourcePath" />
```